# scanf in C leading to infinite loop

Tags: c, recursion, scanf, function-definition

I am trying to write a simple c program that takes input using scanf, and ensures that this input is an integer. To do this I have written a recursive function, but the function goes into an infinite loop if I enter a non-integer character. I've attatched the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getInput() {
  int success = 0;
  int input;

  printf("Enter a positive integer: \n");
  success = scanf(" %d", &input);

  if (success == 0 || input < 0) {
    return getInput();
  }else return input;
}
```

Comment: You have to remove the stuff that`scanf()` can't process as an integer before trying again — but you don't, so it fails again, and recurses again, and ends up crashing.  Probably add: `if (success != 1) { int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ; }` inside your `if` statement.

Comment: `scanf` is arguably not a good tool for parsing uncontrolled input. This is one example of it. An alternative is `fgets` followed by `sscanf`.

Comment: another option would be getline() + strtol() (or sscanf istead of strtol, idk), although management of memory with getline is not super easy, you can learn a thing or two

Comment: Are you testing your code on non-integer input because someone told you it's a case you have to handle, or because you thought it was a good idea?  If the latter, my advice to you is: *just don't worry about it*.  If you're using `scanf`, it turns out that worrying about unexpected input is not a good idea, after all, because properly handling it is next to impossible.  (If you want to properly handle bad input, the first thing to do is to [not use `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537).

Comment: In general, though, recursion is not a good way to "go around again" after rejecting bad input.  Better to just use an ordinary loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if a non-number is entered the input buffer contains a garbage. You need to clear the input buffer before trying to enter another number.

Using your approach with the call of `scanf` the function can look for example the following way

```
int getInput( void ) 
{
    int input = 0;

    printf("Enter a positive integer: \n");
  
    if ( scanf( "%d", &input) != 1 )
    {
        scanf( "%*[^\n]" ); 
    }

    return input <= 0 ? getInput() : input;
}
```

Another more complex approach is to use the function `fgets` and `strtol` and check their results.